# Удаление нескольких items из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем привет!
Есть RecyclerView, которым управляю через адаптер.

Несколько элементов добавляю так:

```
public void addItemsToList(ArrayList<Item> itemsList)
{
    items.addAll(itemsList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Один элемент добавляю так:

```
public void addCommentToList(Item item)
{    
    items.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Для списка прописана возможность множественного выбора элементов и их удаления. На клиенте пользователь выбирает элементы списка, их id отправляется на сервер и при успешном удалении из БД приход ответ.

Знаю, что удалить один элемент можно по его позиции и обновить отображение в адаптере так:

```
public void deleteItemFromList(int position)
{
    items.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Нашёл вариант, когда удаляются несколько элементов, которые следуют друг за другом в списке (через номера позиций, например с 1 по 4), но он не подходит, потому что могут быть выбраны элементы из разных позиций, не идущие друг за другом.

Сейчас я сохраняю позиции элементов для удаления в ArrayList, а потом пытаюсь перебрать их:

```
public void deleteItemsFromList(ArrayList<Integer> positions)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
    {
        items.remove(positions.get(i));
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(positions.get(i));
    }
}
```

Но такой вариант работает некорректно (сначала удаляет элементы, а потом обновляет список и они снова появляются). Думаю, что должен быть какой-то универсальный способ такого удаления.

Вопрос в том, как правильно удалить сразу несколько элементов из списка и обновить его, если известны позиции для удаления?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал это так:

Создал бы в `Adapter` метод вроде такого:

```
public void update(List<Item> items){
    this.items.clear();
    this.items.addAll();
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //вот тут лучше использовать DiffUtils вместо этого метода
}
```

Весь список данных стоит держать где-то за пределами `Adapter`, например `Presenter/ViewModel`. Как только вы нажимаете "удалить N элементов" - вы передаете список этих элементов в ваш `Presenter/ViewModel`, там удаляете их из списка и вызываете метод `update()` адаптера с новыми данными.

Чтоб каждый раз не пересоздавать весь список используйте [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil).

При таком подходе ваш адаптер будет уметь только отрисовывать элементы (соблюдается Принцип единой ответственности), и вы сможете легко изменять его содержимое в любом месте вашего кода.

Единственное, что вам придется решить как вы будете получать список удаляемых элементов.

Comment: Список удаляемых элементов я записываю в ArrayList. С его получением проблем нет) И список с текущими элементами хранится вне адаптера. Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Буду разбираться с DiffUtils.

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html вот тут ещё нет норм пример

Comment: Как раз его нашёл)

Answer (score 1):

Есть альтернативный способ решения проблемы.

1. Поскольку вы берете список из БД, то следует объявить адаптер как `hasStableIds()` и в `Item` завести `id` равный первичному ключу БД (обычно `Long`) откуда вы берете данные
2. Когда вы помечаете элемент на удаление создаете списочек `ArrayList<Long> idsToRemove`, через `adapter.getItemId(position)`
3. Далее проходитесь по списку элементов `idsToRemove`, спокойно все удаляете и вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Я пробовал что-то подобное, но сложность была в том, как прописать удаление и обновления списка в коде, имея id для удаления в idsToRemove.